# Automatically resizing JButton, with aspect ratio

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I'd like to have a JButton which just shows an icon (or image, really). I do like to have the normal button borders so that a user does recognize it's a button that he can click. This button should have a fixed height but resize its width according to the aspect ratio of the its icon.

- Assuming the button insets the image to be drawn by 5px from each edge
- Let's say I've set the preferred and maximum height of the button to 50px.
- Any image that I assign to the button should thus be drawn with a height of 40px and a width that is dependent on the aspect ratio of the image.
- For example, if I assign an image of size 200x100 the result should be that the button should have the size 90x50 (image gets drawn as 80x40, plus 5px border).

Is there a custom JButton class available that can do this? If not, how would I go about implementing this?

**Edit:** BTW, I could just rescale the icon from the outside, but I'd prefer the button to do it.

**Edit 2:** So to me, the biggest issue is: when and how do I determine and set the required button size? Scaling the image for drawing is not a problem.

Comment: @nIcEcOw No, unfortunately that's not helping as it's neither keeping an aspect ratio nor changing its parent button size. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a custom JButton class available that can do this?

Not that I know of.

> If not, how would I go about implementing this?

I'd approach it by extending [`ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) to scale the image.

### E.G.

[image: Scaled images]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class ScaledImageIcon extends ImageIcon {
    ScaledImageIcon(Image image, int height) {
        super(image.getScaledInstance(-1, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    }
}

public class ScalableIcons {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Image img1 = ImageIO.read(
                new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png"));
        final Image img2 = ImageIO.read(
                new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET1EH.png"));
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
                
                final JLabel display = new JLabel();
                display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410,200));
                
                ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String s = e.getActionCommand();
                        switch (s) {
                            case "1":
                                display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                JPanel imageButtons = new JPanel(
                        new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,5,5));

                JButton b1 = new JButton( "1", new ScaledImageIcon(img1,40));
                b1.addActionListener(al);
                imageButtons.add(b1);
                
                JButton b2 = new JButton( "2", new ScaledImageIcon(img2,40));
                b2.addActionListener(al);
                imageButtons.add(b2);
                
                gui.add(imageButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                gui.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I did google, but haven't found anything. The problem might just be that maybe my search-fu is weak. Scaling the image isn't that big of problem, but when/how do I determine and set the button size?

Comment: @DarkDust you don't set the size (nor any of its xxSize properties) of the button .. might help if you elaborate a bit more on your concrete context/use-case

Comment: @kleopatra The use case would be a button that shows an image that the user has selected. Pressing the button allows the user to select a new image. For the UI to look good, the button height should be static but it's OK if it's changing it's width. I can work around that by separating the image-displaying and button part into two components, but a button that would resize automatically would be the nicest solution, IMHO.

Comment: @kleopatra  I've added an example of what I was trying to explain.  Perhaps I misunderstood the problem, but thought the height was both known and fixed/unchanging.

Comment: This looks promising, will test it soon as I can. It's not the "real" solution I was looking for but should be close enough.

Comment: my bad, overcomplicated ;-) Thanks for the example to help me understand.

Comment: @DarkDust thanks for the details, helped me to understand where I went wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the UI or the requirement but maybe Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) will help you out. It automatically resizes the icon based on the components size and has the option to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: I tried using that, but had no luck as it doesn't seem to influence the buttons size. As far as I understand it works fine if I set a fixed button size.